# How to prevent any in an array of terms in a field in a model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-models

Suppose we don't want to allow username to be any of `banned = ['badWordOne', 'otherbadword', 'notthiseither']`

How do we do that?

I tried using [`acceptance`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance) and intuitively changed `accept` to `reject`, but that doesn't work:

```
banned_names = ['badWordOne', 'otherbadword', 'notthiseither']

validates :username, acceptance: { reject: banned_names }, if: :username
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer in [`exclusion`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion)

```
banned_names = ['badWordOne', 'otherbadword', 'notthiseither']

validates :username, exclusion: { in: banned_names }, if: :username
```

Comment: Yes this will work however is"badwordone" an acceptable username? How about "1badWordOne"?

Comment: @engineersmnky great point! In my case I only need to ban exact terms, but if others find their way here it could be very useful to know how to ban terms which contain any of the unwanted words. (my use case is simply to stop duplicate routes since some routes look like `domain.com/:username`. So it would be bad if someone made their username 'user', or 'product' for example (since that conflict with the routes for some resources). I'd be curious to know how to ban terms that contain any sub string(s) in the array

Comment: probably would want to look at the [`format`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format) validation